# How to pass text box value to sibling component in react on button click

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass text box value to sibling component on button click. I have one parent component called as **App.js**. And **App.js** have two child component called as **TextComponent.js** and **TableComponent.js**.

I want to pass **TextComponent.js** value to **TableComponent.js** on button click. This two component are siblings.
Here is my code.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import TextComponent from './TextComponent'
import TableComponent from './TableComponent'
import VAL from './TextComponent'
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      fieldVal: ""
    }
 }

 onUpdate = (val) => {
   this.setState({
     fieldVal: val
   })
 };

 render() {
   return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextComponent onUpdate={this.onUpdate}></TextComponent>
      <br />
      <TableComponent passedVal={this.state.fieldVal}></TableComponent>
   </div>
  );
}

}
export default App;
```

TextComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Input, Label } from 'reactstrap';

class TextComponent extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
     fieldVal: ""
   }
   this.update = this.update.bind(this);
 }

 update = (e) => {
   console.log(e.target.value);
   this.props.onUpdate(e.target.value);
   this.setState({fieldVal: e.target.value});
 };

 render() {
   return (
     <Form >
       <FormGroup >
         <Label for="Text" >
           Enter Text
         </Label>
         <Input
           type="text"
           name="text"
           placeholder="Eneter Text"
           value={this.state.fieldVal}
         />
         <Button onClick={this.update}>Save Details</Button>
       </FormGroup>
     </Form>
   );
 }
}
export default TextComponent;
```

TableComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Input, Label, Table } from 'reactstrap';

class TableComponent extends React.Component {

   render() {
       const { textValue } = this.props;
       return (
          <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <Input
                            type="text"
                            name="text"
                            value={this.props.passedVal}
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td><Button>*</Button></td>
                    <td><Button>^</Button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
}
 export default TableComponent;
```

I'm not getting how to do it. I'm very new with React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `onChange` event on `Input`,

```
<Input
    type="text"
    name="text"
    placeholder="Eneter Text"
    value={this.state.fieldVal}
    onChange={this.onChangehandler}
/>
```

And `onChangehandler` function should be,

```
onChangehandler = (e) =>{
  this.setState({fieldVal: e.target.value})
}
```

And finally your `update` function should be

```
update = () => {
   this.props.onUpdate(this.state.fieldVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the code in TextComponent.js and App.js.

TextComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Input, Label } from 'reactstrap';

class TextComponent extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
     fieldVal: ""
   }
   this.update = this.update.bind(this);
 }

 update = (e) => {
   console.log(e.target.value);
   this.props.onUpdate(e.target.value);
   this.setState({fieldVal: e.target.value});
 };

 render() {
   return (
     <Form >
       <FormGroup >
         <Label for="Text" >
           Enter Text
         </Label>
         <Input
           type="text"
           name="text"
           placeholder="Eneter Text"
           value={this.state.fieldVal}
         />
         <Button onClick={() => this.props.onUpdate(this.state.fieldVal)}>Save Details</Button>
       </FormGroup>
     </Form>
   );
 }
}
export default TextComponent;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import TextComponent from './TextComponent'
import TableComponent from './TableComponent'
import VAL from './TextComponent'
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      fieldVal: ""
    }
 }

 onUpdate = (val) => {
   this.setState({
     fieldVal: val
   })
 };

 render() {
   return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextComponent onUpdate={(val) => this.onUpdate(val)}></TextComponent>
      <br />
      <TableComponent passedVal={this.state.fieldVal}></TableComponent>
   </div>
  );
}

}
export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm getting **[object Object]** value in TableComponent.js.